# Variable name from command output

Tags: bash, environment-variables, string

I have some string, and want to split on colon ":" assigning on variable with name from left part and value from right part. For example:

`echo "Title: Some title" | sed 's/:.*//'`

gives me wanted variable name "Title", and:

`echo "Title: Some title" | sed 's/.*: //'`

gives me the value "Some title".

My problem is how to assign variable named "Title" by the output of above command.

I can assign the value like `$(echo "Title: Some title" | sed 's/.*: //)` but can't find how to assign the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how this is going to be used and your bash version, you would probably be better off using an [associative array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

Failing that, I suggest you [fake one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/688849/900873).

For the sake of completeness, you can actually do this using `eval`.  **Note that eval is dangerous and you shouldn't use this unless you have to.**

```
eval "${string/: /=\"}\""
```

Comment: Seems like great idea. I have "GNU bash, version 4.2.8" and script returns [unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"']. I'm looking for possible solutions right now...

Comment: @zetah change the single quotes to escaped doubles.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather strange thing to be doing, but I guess you could construct an `export` statement:

```
$ export $(echo "Title: Some title" | sed 's/:.*//')="$(echo "Title: Some title" | sed 's/.*: //')"
$ echo $Title
Some title
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess there is no other way then exporting as environment variable? I mean I can't make local variable name from command output?

Comment: You can craft the assignment using bash string manipulation. If I haven't made a mistake, I believe it would be (assuming the string is in a variable `string`) `"${string/: /='}'"`

Comment: @zetah you're better off with this, but if you really need a local, see my answer.

Comment: Make that `${string/: /=\"}\""`

Comment: @zetah You can use `typeset` or `local` instead of `export`, if your shell has them (bash does).

Answer (score 0):

May be this will give the expected result

```
#!/bin/sh
export Variablename="$(echo "Title: Some title" | awk -F':' '{ print $1}')=\"$(echo "Title: Some title" | awk -F':' '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//g')\""
```

***Output :***

Title="Some title"